# How to access my dockerized app outside the server?

Tags: postgresql, docker, docker-compose, deployment, pgadmin

I have created an app with four services that I have dockerized, backend (port 5000), frontend (port 5173), postgres (port 5432) and pgadmin (port 5555). Once dockerized I have pushed the images to dockerHub and pull them in the remote server with an IP_Server_X. I wonder how to make my app available for the public using my IP adress. Here is my server docker-compose file:

```
version: '2.3'

services:
  my_frontend:
    image: username/frontend:v0
    restart: always
    environment:
      - REACT_APP_API_SERVER=http://111.55.66.888:5000 # Server IP adress
    ports:
      - "5173:80"
    networks:
      - my_network
    env_file:
      - .env
    depends_on:
      - my_backend

  my_backend:
    image: username/backend:v0
    env_file:
      - .env
    command: bash -c 'while !</dev/tcp/my_db/5432; do sleep 1; done; bash run.sh'
    restart: always
    ports:
      - "5000:5000"
    networks:
      - my_network
    depends_on:
      - my_db

  my_db:
    image: username/postgres:v0
    env_file:
      - .env
    volumes:
      - /home/client/data:/var/lib/postgresql/data/pgdata
    restart: always
    ports:
      - "54320:5432"
    networks:
      - my_network
    healthcheck:
      test: ["CMD-SHELL", "pg_isready -U admin -d my_db"]
      interval: 10s
      timeout: 5s
      retries: 5

  my_db_viewer:
    image: username/pgadmin:v0
    env_file:
      - .env
    restart: always
    ports:
      - "5555:5555"
    networks:
      - my_network
    depends_on:
      - my_db

networks:
  my_network:
    driver: bridge
```

Answer (score 0):

Your app should be available at `http://FRONTEND_IP:5173`.

Comment: you mean http://111.55.66.888:5173. but unfortunately it is not.

Comment: What is the error message? Or is there any firewall in the remote server?

Comment: I have opened necessary ports like 5173, 5000, and 5555 using sudo ufw allow 5173/tcp. I tried to send request to the API in the port 5000 using Insomnia but I got an error : Error: Couldn't connect to server